# C# class instantiation const string

Tags: c#, constants, heap-memory

I've read that const string objects are stored as value and have their value assigned at compile time. Does this mean memory is allocated even if the encapsulating class is not instantiated i.e. can waste heap space if the const keyword over used (too many const strings)?

**Edit:** some context...

I require a lot of constant value `string` objects, some which will definately be used and others that will be used depending on the user's interaction (i.e. for specific use cases only). The 1st set of string which I know will be used I have declared in a `static` class as `const` objects. The remaining strings, should they also be declared with `const` or will this use up unnecessary heap space if those specific use cases are never triggered?

Comment: I'm no expert here, but if the run-time sees that the `const` field is not going to be used, I don't think it will have to allocate the object on the heap. But I also don't think it is required to refrain from allocating it. Maybe this is no different than a non-const field that is never used? In any case, *if* the `const` field is ever used, there will only ever be one instance of it on the heap because a `const` string will be subject to *string interning*.

Answer (score 2):

If you strings are static properties of your class they will be allocated if not they will no be allocated until they are instanciated

String interning is a proccess thast is used improve memory and heap usage and allow for more efficient string comparison

**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning**

**http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html**

Comment: Thanks, I added some extra detail to the original post too.